# Are M8 screws double the size of M4 screws?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bolting

Found some printable M8 screws on Thingiverse (https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4805480), which made me wonder if I can get M4 screws, just by resizing them factor 0.5.

Comment: Nope, and in addition / FYI, there are multiple fine thread versions that are  used fairly often (e.g. in automobiles), so it's not enough to refer to an "M8",  but must specify M8x1.25 or M8x1 or M8x.75

Comment: @PeteW If I had to guess though, I would always guess the coarse thread.

Comment: @PeteW - In my experience with both; the convention in ASME drawings is to always state the pitch with the size, ISO based drawing convention is to state the pitch only when it is _not_ coarse. Saves trying to remember all of the coarse pitch sizes at least!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ISO metric bolt has its diameter as the numeral part of the name.

So M8 has a diameter of 8mm compared to that of the M4 bolt. So far scaling would make sense.

However, the pitch of them is not proportional and would be wrong if you scale them.

her is a figure from Wikipedia.  [Wiki](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/ISO_metric_screw_thread)

.

[image]